# Assign JSON response to state React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, laravel-5, react-native

I am using Laravel and React Native to build a project. I have a post request and which validates data at server side and returns errors. I want to assign the error response in the errors array which has been declared at state. My code are given below :

Laravel:

```
public function registerUser(Request $request) 
{
    $rules = [
        'username' => 'required', 
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:5'
    ];

    $validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

    if ($validator->fails()) {    
        return response()->json(['errors' => $validator->messages()]);
    }

    $user = User::create(request(['username', 'email', 'password']));

    return response()->json('success');
}
```

React Native:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            userName:'',
            userEmail:'', 
            userPassword:'',
            errors:[]               
        }
    }

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: API_URL+'signup',
        data: {
            username: userName,
            email: userEmail,
            password: userPassword
        }
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        var count = Object.keys(response.data.errors).length;
        if (count > 0) {
            console.log(response.data.errors);
            var newState = new Array(); 
            newState.push(response.data.errors);
            this.setState({
                errors: newState
            })
        }
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

It shows me error the below error at console:

**undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setState({errors: newState})')**
*** app\components\Registration\RegistrationForm.js:51:18 in 
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123:25 in 
- ... 10 more stack frames from framework internals**

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly bind your functions to get the correct `this` context or use ES6 arrow functions that is already bound to the correct `this` context

Check the code below

```
axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: API_URL+'signup',
        data: {
            username: userName,
            email: userEmail,
            password: userPassword
        }
    })
    .then((response) => {
        var count = Object.keys(response.data.errors).length;
        if (count > 0) {
            console.log(response.data.errors);
            var newState = new Array(); 
            newState.push(response.data.errors);
            this.setState({
                errors: newState
            })
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```